# Unable to Invoke a Lambda Function with Aurora MySQL Native Function

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I'm using aurora version 1.16 and want to trigger a lambda function on an insert into the table. I've been following the steps in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html#AuroraMySQL.Integrating.NativeLambda and try to invoke the lambda synchronously.

However, I failed to grant privilege on INVOKE_LAMBDA to the user I chose. I've ran the script GRANT INVOKE LAMBDA ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%'; however it showed an syntax error on GRANT, which also means that MySQL couldn't recognize INVOKE LAMBDA as a privilege.

I could use the stored procedure to invoke lambda asynchronously but i'm still hoping to find a way to make use of the native function method, given that the aurora version I'm using is supposed to support that.

Thanks if anyone can help

Comment: In mentioned documentation you have the following note: "You can call the native functions lambda_sync and lambda_async when you use Aurora MySQL version 1.16 and later. " Currently you use Aurora version 1.6, therefore you cannot setup this feature.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped earlier. I am using Aurora version 1.16

Comment: *"however it showed an syntax error on GRANT"*  Please show the complete error message, exactly as it appears.

Comment: It shows 'Syntax error: unexpected 'GRANT'' which i think is because INVOKE LAMBDA isn't recognized as a previlege

Comment: That isn't a MySQL syntax error.  If it were, it would look like this: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '...'`  The error you see is coming from your client.  MySQL Workbench is notorious for trying to be "helpful" like this and throwing errors due to its own deficiencies.  Try a different client such as the `mysql` CLI or check for possible upgrades for whatever client you are using.